# Using datatable with node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, datatables

I am trying to use jquery Datatable with Node.js.
Here is my Code HTML

```
<button id="btnSearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-responsive"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>

<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <div id="tableContainer">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTables1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">base</th>
                <th class="text-left">base1</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
            <img id="loading-image" src="../dist/img/loading_spinner.gif" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is script code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        RefreshTable("#dataTables1");
    });

    function RefreshTable(tableId) {

        table = $(tableId).dataTable();
        table._fnClearTable(table.oSettings);
        table.fnDestroy();
        table.fnDraw(true);
        var table2 = $(tableId).dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            oLanguage: {
                sProcessing: "<img src='../dist/img/loading_spinner.gif'/>"
            },
            "aLengthMenu": [10, 30, 50, 100],
            "pageLength": 30,
            "sAjaxSource": 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/statistic?schemename=abc',
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            },
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'dataTables_wrapper'ip>>",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",//"full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sName": "base", "bSortable": false },//0
                { "sName": "base1", "bSortable": false }
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
```

And here is my code server side node js

```
var async = require('async'),
    QueryBuilder = require('datatable');

var tableDefinition = {
    sTableName: 'Orgs'
};

var queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(tableDefinition);

// requestQuery is normally provided by the DataTables AJAX call
var requestQuery = {
    iDisplayStart: 0,
    iDisplayLength: 5
};

// Build an object of SQL statements
var queries = queryBuilder.buildQuery(requestQuery);   

exports.test = function(req, res){
        console.log(req.query.schemename);

        userExport.getUserEdit(req.query.schemename, function(rows){
            res.json(queryBuilder.parseResponse(rows));
        })
    }
```

When i clicked in the search button then in the server side i recieved schemename is 'abc' and got the user but i can't response the json to table. In the tab console of browser i got a error :
jquery.dataTables.js:4108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, anyone help me out of this error or suggest me a solution to fix this problem thank for adventure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sAjaxDataProp: 'data'` to your initialization params :

```
var table2 = $(tableId).dataTable({
  ...
  sAjaxDataProp: 'data',
  sAjaxSource: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/statistic?schemename=abc',
  ...
})
```

Reason: When using `sAjaxSource`, dataTables 1.9.x expect data to be in the format `{ "aaData" : [...] }`, thats why you get the *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*. However, `node-datatable` exports the rows as `{ "data" : [...] }`.

Comment: thank you i added this and fix the type error, but i can't bind the data to datatable my return data is json object

Comment: Hey @beginerdeveloper - have investigated the source code ->  https://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable/blob/master/lib/builder.js  QueryBuilder wraps the table rows into a `data` section, so change to `sAjaxDataProp: 'data'` ...